# Php Mysql Pagination

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, pagination

I've faced this problem trying to do some easy and simple pagination from some tutorial, but apparently it's not working the way it should be.. let me post some code that is well commented out and preview the problem i'm facing: -

First of all I've a file named FAQ_content which has the following code: -

```
    <?php 
include ('config/setup.php'); //database connection file!
##Database Retrieval Query: -
    ##FAQ_Retrieval_Query: -
        ##Pagination Logic
        //This Query is Only to get the number of rows.. we'll use a second part downstairs.
        $FAQ_query="SELECT * FROM FAQ_content ORDER BY id ASC ";
        $data1 = mysql_query($FAQ_query);
        $nr = mysql_num_rows($data1); // counts the number of entries within the database table.
        if (isset ($_GET['pn']))
            {
                $pn=preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i','',$_GET['pn']); //filters everything but numbers for security 
            }else {// if the URL variable has no $pn then it will be set to 1.
                $pn=1;
            }
        $itemsPerPage= 5; //How many items do we wanna view per page?
        $lastPage = ceil($nr/$itemsPerPage); //number of entries in the database divided by the number we wanna show per page.
        if ($pn <1) { 
                // if the pagenumber is less than 1, then it'll be forced to one,
                //and if it's larger than last page, it'll be forced to last page.
                $pn=1;}
                else if ($pn>$lastPage){
                    $pn = $lastPage;
                    }
        //Creating the Numbers to click between next and back buttons..
        $centerPages = ""; //just initiating the variable.
        $sub1 =  $pn - 1;
        $sub2 = $pn - 2;
        $add1 = $pn + 1;
        $add2 = $pn + 2;
        if ($pn == 1)
        {
            $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">'.$pn.'</span>&nbsp;';
            $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$add1.'">'.$add1.'</a> &nbsp;';
        }else if ($pn == $lastPage) 
        {
            $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$sub1.'">'.$sub1.'</a> &nbsp;';
            $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">'.$pn.'</span>&nbsp;';
        }else if ($pn > 2 && $pn < ($lastPage-1)) {
            $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$sub2.'">'.$sub2.'</a> &nbsp;';
            $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$sub1.'">'.$sub1.'</a> &nbsp;';
            $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">'.$pn.'</span>&nbsp;';
            $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$add1.'">'.$add1.'</a> &nbsp;';
            $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$add2.'">'.$add2.'</a> &nbsp;';
        }else if ($pn >1 && $pn < $lastPage) {
            $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$sub1.'">'.$sub1.'</a> &nbsp;';
            $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">'.$pn.'</span>&nbsp;';
            $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$add1.'">'.$add1.'</a> &nbsp;';
        }
        //Setting the limit range for the number of data retrieved and the items per page.
        $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage;   
        $FAQ_query2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM FAQ_content ORDER BY id ASC $limit " , $dbc) or die(mysql_error());
        ##Pagination Logic End-- :(
        ##Pagination Display Options : -
        $paginationDisplay = "";// just initialising..
        //This condition runs only if the last page is not equal to 1, if it is equal to 1, then we don't require links.
        if ($lastPage != "1") {
            //showing the user what page he is on, and what number of pages are there..
            $paginationDisplay .= 'Page <strong>' .$pn. '</strong> of' .$lastPage. '<img src="images/clearimage.png" width="48px" height="1px" alt="Spacer"/>'; 
                //if we're not on page 1 we can place a back button ^_^
                if ($pn != 1) {
                    $previous = $pn - 1;
                    $paginationDisplay .= '&nbsp; <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$previous.'"> Back </a>';  
                }
                //Lay in the clickable numbers display here between the back and next links ^_^.
                $paginationDisplay .='<span class="paginationNumbers">'.$centerPages.'</span>';
                //If we're not on the very last page, a next button is placed :-
                if ($pn != $lastPage) {
                    $nextPage = $pn +1;
                    $paginationDisplay .= '&nbsp; <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$nextPage.'"> Next </a>';  
                }
        }       
?>
```

that's the first file that has all the pagination rules and logic in addition to the pagination display which formats how it is going to show up.. now moving on to the problem itself..

I included the file mentioned above into my main file where i wanna view the data, (HINT:- the database in the previous queries has 23 entries, and i've tested that numrows sees the 23 entries by echoing it..)
The data in the database are 23 entries, in three fields id, title and text..
title is supposedly the header, text is the body of each FAQ to be retrieved.
The code that may have the issue is: -

```
            <div class="FAQWrapper">
            <?php 
                include ('content/FAQ-content.php');
                $output1='';
                $output2='';
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($FAQ_query2)) {
                    $title = $row['title'];
                    $text = $row['text'];
                    $output ='<div class="FAQInstance">
                    <div class="FAQHeader"><h2>'.$title.'</h2></div><div class="FAQDetails"><p>'.$text.'</p></div></div>';
                    //$output2 ='<div class="FAQDetails"><p>'.$text.'</p></div>';
                }
             ?>
        <!--FAQ Instance Start-->
            <?php echo $output; ?>
            <!--FAQ Header Start-->
            <!--FAQ Header Ends-->
            <!--FAQ Details Start-->
            <!--FAQ Details Ends-->
        <!--FAQ Instance Ends-->
        <!--Pagination Display Start-->
        <div style="margin-left:58px; margin-right:58px; padding:6px; background-color:#FFF; border:#999 1px solid; float:right;"><?php echo $paginationDisplay; ?></div>
        <!--Pagination Display Ends-->
    </div>
    <!-- FAQ Content Ends-->
```

what i'm getting is : - http://wassatproject.com/FAQ.php
as you can see it's a single output from the database, in addition to the (very well working) pagination buttons at the bottom..

What i'm trying to do is view 5 items per page.. that are divided into their divs, where FAQ wrapper is the big wrapper holding two nested divs on same level inside which is header div and details div.. header takes the title from the database while details take the text in the database and associates it with its header.. that's all i wanna do..

I'm really thankful in advance for your help.. please notify me if you needed any information in addition to the massive amounts that I've so far provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried a new method, since I've been trying ever since i posted the question, i thought of trying something that has solved the issue, as you cans see here's the new code.. all the problem was with the main file named FAQ.php, not with the FAQ-content.php..
here's the code after I've fixed it.. Thanks for your hospitality ^_^

```
<!-- FAQ Content Start-->
<div class="FAQWrapper">
        <?php 
            include ('content/FAQ-content.php');
            $output1='';
            $output2='';
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($FAQ_query2)) {
                $title = $row['title'];
                $text = $row['text'];
                $output ='<div class="FAQInstance">
                <div class="FAQHeader"><h2>'.$title.'</h2></div><div class="FAQDetails"><p>'.$text.'</p></div></div>';
                echo $output;
            }
         ?>
    <!--FAQ Instance Start-->
        <!--FAQ Header Start-->
        <!--FAQ Header Ends-->
        <!--FAQ Details Start-->
        <!--FAQ Details Ends-->
    <!--FAQ Instance Ends-->
    <!--Pagination Display Start-->
    <div style="margin-left:58px; margin-right:58px; padding:6px; background-color:#FFF; border:#999 1px solid; float:right;"><?php echo $paginationDisplay; ?></div>
    <!--Pagination Display Ends-->
</div>
<!-- FAQ Content Ends-->
```

Apparently the guy who've made the famous tutorial on youtube who's name is Adam Khoury has made this mistake here on his site :- http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=289
but apparently i managed to solve it with your help guys ^_^

Answer (score -1):

**you can use mysqli, code is below**

```
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ui");


$start=0;
$limit=5;

  $t=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from form_table");
  $total=mysqli_num_rows($t);



   if(isset($_GET['id']))
   {
        $id=$_GET['id'] ; 
                        $start=($id-1)*$limit;

                          }
            else
            {
        $id=1;
 }
    $page=ceil($total/$limit);

   $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from form_table limit $start,$limit");
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet"                    href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script s        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">     </script>
 <script                      src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">              </script>
  </head>         
 <body>

<div class="container">
 <h2>Table</h2>
    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Id</th>
         <th>Name</th>
       <th>Gender</th>


<th>Hobbies</th>
<th>Course</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

 <?php
    while($ft=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
 {?>
 <tr>
 <td><?= $ft['0']?></td>
 <td><?= $ft['1']?></td>
 <td><?= $ft['2']?></td>
 <td><?= $ft['3']?></td>
 <td><?= $ft['4']?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php
 }

  ? >


    </tbody>
    </table>
    <ul class="pagination">
       <?php if($id > 1) {?> <li><a href="?id=<?php echo ($id-1) ?              >">Previous</a></li><?php }?>
     <?php
     for($i=1;$i <= $page;$i++){
    ?>
    <li><a href="?id=<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i;?></a></li>
   <?php
   }
   ?>
 <?php if($id!=$page)

  {?>
```